# Firebase Anonymous Login on Form Submit Issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm trying to make it so that when I user clicks the submit button on my sign in form, they will be signed in as an anonymous user in Firebase. I know my submit button is triggering the jQuery submit event because the alert in it is being displayed. However, even though the submit button triggers the jQuery submit event, the `signInAnonymously` method is not being called for some reason. I've also tried using a putting the `signInAnonymously` call in a separate function and using the form `onsubmit` attribute but that did not work either. Here is my code (I've omitted my config details for security purposes):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <!-- Required meta tags always come first -->
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
        <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge">

        <title>Escape Room</title>

        <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="resources/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css">

        <!-- Custom CSS -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">

        <!-- jQuery -->
        <script src="resources/jquery/jquery-3.1.1.slim.min.js"></script>

        <!-- Firebase -->
        <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/3.6.2/firebase-app.js"></script>
        <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/3.6.2/firebase-auth.js"></script>
        <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/3.6.2/firebase-database.js"></script>
        <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/3.6.2/firebase-messaging.js"></script>


        <script>
            // Initialize Firebase
            var config = {
                apiKey: "",
                authDomain: "",
                databaseURL: "",
                storageBucket: "",
                messagingSenderId: ""
            };
            firebase.initializeApp(config);

            //Initialize authentication
            var auth = firebase.auth();

            // Handle authenticated users
            auth.onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
                if (user) {
                    // User is signed in.
                    var isAnonymous = user.isAnonymous;
                    var uid = user.uid;
                    // ...
                } else {
                    // User is signed out.
                    // ...
                }
                // ...
            });

            // When the DOM has loaded
            $(document).ready(function(e) {

                $('#signIn').submit(function(e) {
                    // Prevent the page from refreshing
                    e.preventDefault();

                    alert("test");

                    // Authenticate user
                    auth.signInAnonymously().catch(function(error) {
                        alert('test2');
                        // Handle Errors here.
                        var errorCode = error.code;
                        var errorMessage = error.message;

                        console.error(error);
                    });
                });
            });

        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-12">
                    <form id="signIn">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="name">Name</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Your Name">
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="vest">Vest Number</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Vest Number">
                        </div>

                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Start</button>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>



        <!-- jQuery first, then Tether, then Bootstrap JS. -->
        <script src="resources/jquery/jquery-3.1.1.slim.min.js"></script>
        <script src="resources/tether/js/tether.min.js"></script>
        <script src="resources/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

I'm relatively new to Firebase and this has got me baffled, so any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Are you sure it's not being called? The function you registered in `auth.onAuthStateChanged` should be fired, try adding an alert there as well. (You might see that it gets fired on page load as well.)

Comment: @ArneHugo I tried adding an alert in `auth.onAuthStateChanged` but it did not fire. I also do not see a user created in the Firebase console which would happen if the function was fired.

Comment: Does the `alert("test");` show?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen yes it does. I added a second alert to my code for clarification. `alert("test");` shows but `alert('test2');` does not show which is how I know `auth.signInAnonymously()` is not being called.

Comment: @ArneHugo just for further clarification when I added the alert to `auth.onAuthStateChanged` it did fire when the page loaded but did not fire again when I pressed the submit button.

Answer (score 2):

I found out what was going wrong. Since I never called `firebase.auth().signOut()` it was keeping me logged in as the same user so it did not create a new user each time I submitted the form because I was already logged in as a user. I added `window.onload = auth.signOut();` to the script in my head and now a new user is created each time I press the submit button.